# Need to change strong passphrase for Private folder

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I want to sync .Private on two computers through Ubuntu One.  Problem is that the two computers have different strong passphrases for the Private folder.  I have the passphrases recorded on paper.  I have not put any data in the Private folder yet on either computer.  What would be the way to change the passphrase on one machine to match the other.  Both computers are running 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any data in the Private folder yet, then you simply need to copy the contents of one of the `~/.ecryptfs/` directories to the other machine.

The files in that directory (specifically `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` and `~/.ecryptfs/Private.sig`) determine the keys that will be used to do the encryption.

Note that if the login passphrase is different on the two machines, you'll need to use [ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase) to ensure that your Private directory is mounted at login.